# Getting Ubuntu to remember settings for Twitch TV

Tags: settings

I only really noticed it on Twitch but everything I go to watch a stream I have to force it to go to the highest quality. Usually if you choose a setting it will always be there but I can go to the same stream and it doesn't remember it.

Comment: You don't provide enough information for an exact answer. What browser are you using to watch Twitch TV?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the privacy settings in your browser to allow Twitch TV to store cookies on your system. Problem solved.